# Bind key sequence to ESC in zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh

How can I bin a key sequence to ESC in zsh?

I wish to do the following

```
bindkey "jj" <esc>
```

but cannot find the code for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> is ASCII `0x1B`, so all of **`\e`**, **`\x1b`** or **`\033`** should work.

Comment: Yes, but the bindkey only seems to allow you to bind to widgets.  I did manage to solve this in the end by binding to vi-cmd-mode which is what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: I wonder if this will allow me to bind custom sequence like ;; to enter into the ZLE vi mode. Can you please provide me with full command for .zshrc to change binding? Thanks!

Comment: @A.B: It's documented in `man zshzle`. It should work, but it might become quite annoying to type a lone `;` as ZLE will not display it until you enter the *next* character.